# Azure WebJob Logs Console shows wrong symbols, but the IDE Console shows correct output

Tags: .net, azure, console, rider, binance

I use Rider IDE to develop Dot.Net app, which I deploy to Microsoft Azure as a WebJob. For test purposes I output Json strings from WebSocket (it listens Binance UserStream), I found a weird problem, when Azure Logs Console shows a lot of unsupported symbols at the end these strings, while Rider IDE Console doesn't:

[Correct Rider Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjWjP.png)

[Wrong Azure Logs Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvCi.png)

Looks like situation is related to Console OutputEncoding, so I tried to setup it at the app start, but it doesn't fix the problem:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Perhaps, I need to somehow escape this strings before I log them for correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at the end I found the problem: WebSocket reads data into buffer with fixed size, then it's returning as a string, which literally has the same size as buffer. When I output this string to Console, Rider shows only Json part of the string, but the WebJob Log outputs Json part + all nullable characters at the end.

I added this simple code to output only Json part of the string, assuming every Json ends with '}' character:

```
int lastCharacterIndex = data.LastIndexOf('}');
Console.WriteLine($"Trader::OnMessageReceived(): {data.Substring(0, lastCharacterIndex + 1)}");
```